# Malaysia Airlines Flight 370 - Why didn't Malaysian Air Force scramble jets?

Tags: military

It seems odd that a large commercial aircraft can deviate radically from its scheduled flight path without the military doing something about the situation. Malaysian military radar tracked the plane for about an hour after said aircraft had dropped off the air traffic controllers radar.

Why were no jets scrambled?

Has Malaysia not heard of "9/11", and how commercial aircraft were used by terrorists?

Which other countries military also pays such little heed "9/11"?

Comment: Welcome to SE.Aviation. This is largely an opinion based question, however you may be able to reword it to make it fit within our guidelines if you are curious about Malaysian jet scrambling protocols please word it as so.

Comment: *Which other countries military also pays such little heed "9/11"*: The question is provocative, but the answer is sad. Many countries are more concerned about not dying before being 40 years old, and eating something, than looking for a threat that will never come because it wouldn't move anyone to tears in wealthy countries.

Comment: You can't really blame the Malaysian Air Force as they only monitor Air Force aircraft, not a random civilian jet flying off route.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple reasons for this:

- The aircraft stopped communicating *after* the Kula Lumpur asked the aircraft to contact Ho Chi Minh ACC. The last verbal contact with the aircraft is this:

> Lumpur Radar: "Malaysian three seven zero, contact Ho Chi Minh one two zero decimal nine. Good night."
>
> Flight 370: "Good night. Malaysian three seven zero."

The Kula Lumpur Control had no way of knowing whether the aircraft had contacted as instructed (and acknowledged).

- According to the [Malaysian defence minister](http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/malaysia-airlines-mh370-defence-ministry-defends-not-sending-jet-1.2647197), the aircraft was deemed commercial and not hostile.
- Even if the aircraft was tracked in radar by the military, that in itself is not sufficient for scrambling jets. Usually, the ATC will inform the authorities about any possible deviation; It is unlikely that the military would have real time details of aircraft routes. Note that it was not possible in this case (the aircraft transponder had gone silent before deviating from path). Also, there can be multiple reasons for loss of communications (usually equipment failure), and one does not immediately conclude that the aircraft has been hijacked.
- Scrambling jets is usually the last resort and are sent to [shoot the non-responsive aircraft](http://foxtrotalpha.jalopnik.com/listen-to-the-threat-youll-hear-if-you-screw-with-briti-1652997879). You don't shoot a civil aircraft with hundreds of passengers just because a microphone stopped working. The ATC must confirm that it had deviated from path and then the aircraft must be deemed a credible threat.
- While the procedures for scrambling military aircraft are usually classified, it can be assumed that they are different in case of US (and Europe) and rest of the world. It takes a lot of resources to keep aircraft and pilots ready to intercept aircraft, which not all countries have (or even require most of the time).

Comment: Fighters are _not_ sent to _shoot_ the non-responsibe aircraft. They are sent to _identify_ the aircraft, _check_ what kind of problem it might have and _guide_ it to suitable nearby airport. They can shoot it as their last resort if it does not respond to the visual commands either, but they have many tasks and options that are far from last resort.

Comment: @JanHudec You're right. But I made that point in reference to the statement made by the Malaysian defense minister- ["If you're not going to shoot it down, what's the point of sending it (a fighter) up?" Hishammuddin asked](http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/malaysia-airlines-mh370-defence-ministry-defends-not-sending-jet-1.2647197). I'm not sure about the standard response of Malaysian defense forces as far as interception of hijacked aircraft is concerned; So, I'd answered it in light of the statement of defense minister, who as far as I know is responsible for handling this kind of stuff.